# `mail` command - How can I display the email list again?

Tags: mail-command

When using the `mail` command, I automatically get the list of the emails received:

```
user@server:~ $ mail
"/var/mail/user": 4 messages 4 unread
>U  1 mail1      Tue Dec 17 13:13   18/628   junk_mail
 U  2 mail2      Tue Dec 17 13:14   18/628   junk_mail
 U  3 mail3      Tue Dec 17 13:15   18/628   very important!
 U  4 mail4      Tue Dec 17 13:16   18/628   blabla
?
```

**How can I get that list again, without relaunching?**
The `print` command shows the *content* of the mail.

Example:
I want to delete `mail1 - junk_mail`, I type `? delete 1`. OK.
If I want to delete `mail2 - junk_mail`, I need to type `? delete 1` again. Because after typing the first command, the mail list changed to:

```
user@server:~ $ mail
"/var/mail/user": 3 messages 3 unread
>U  1 mail2      Tue Dec 17 13:14   18/628   junk_mail
 U  2 mail3      Tue Dec 17 13:15   18/628   very important!
 U  3 mail4      Tue Dec 17 13:16   18/628   blabla
?
```

I'm OK with that too. However, if I made a mistake, I could possibly delete an important mail. If I typed `? delete 2`, I would have deleted `mail3 - very important!` because the mail index changed. I could do the math in my head, but that is not the point here.

Comment: Why are you not using `mutt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have references, but from memory try `h` (for headers).

There is also `?` for other misc commands.